# WorkerService TCPListener in Azure Container

Tags: c#, azure, docker, .net-core, tcplistener

First, I'm sorry for the English, I'm using Google Translate.

I need to create a TCPListener service so that my PLC can send data via IP and PORT

For this solution, I created a WorkerService .net core 3.1 and hosted the app inside a linux container with .net core

**DockerFile:**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR / app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR / src
COPY ["FarkServerWorker / FarkServerWorker.csproj", "FarkServerWorker /"]
RUN dotnet restore "FarkServerWorker / FarkServerWorker.csproj"
COPY. .
WORKDIR "/ src / FarkServerWorker"
Dotnet build RUN "FarkServerWorker.csproj" -c Release -o / app / build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FarkServerWorker.csproj" -c Release -o / app / publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR / app
COPY --from = publish / app / publish.

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FarkServerWorker.dll"]
```

I configured my csproj and includes an 8000:5000 port mapping parameter

**.csproj:**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-FarkServerWorker-FB1AB114-8679-48FC-826C-BF42B6F51505</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileRunArguments>-p 6000:5000</DockerfileRunArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

when running the localhost docker the communication worked perfectly

ClienteTcp (Console):

```
using var ClienteTCP = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 6000);
using var Stream = ClienteTCP.GetStream();

//Request
var DataRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Mensagem);
Stream.Write(DataRequest, 0, DataRequest.Length);

//Response
var DataResponse = new Byte[256];
var BytesResponse = Stream.Read(DataResponse, 0, DataResponse.Length);
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(DataResponse, 0, BytesResponse);
```

TCPServer (WorkerService):

```
var ServerTCP = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
ServerTCP.Start();

var BytesReceived = new Byte[256];

while (true)
{
    using var ClienteRecebido = await ServerTCP.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    using var Stream = ClienteRecebido.GetStream();

    int i;
    while ((i = Stream.Read(BytesReceived, 0, BytesReceived.Length)) != 0)
    {
        var DataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BytesReceived, 0, i);
        var DataResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DataReceived.ToUpper());
        Stream.Write(DataResponse, 0, DataResponse.Length);

        _logger.LogInformation("Recebido: {0}", DataReceived);
    }
}
```

as i said, this works perfectly when running the docker with the command:

```
docker container run -d -p 6000: 5000 farkapp
```

But when I post to azure, I can't send and receive data

[image]

I use the application's virtual IP, and port 6000, but it doesn't work, only localhost works

Errors:

[image]